# Could we export or import Visual C++ 6.0 Directories setting?

Tags: visual-c++, ide, visual-c++-6

[image]

My project have a lot setting in Visual C++ 6.0 setting: Tool > Option > Directories

Include/Link/Source files

Is there any way to save these settings into a file or where is it in VC 6.0?

I want use this setting in another computer.

Comment: In the project file, I think.  Look at the .dsp file with Notepad.  Memory fails me, you asked this question 14 years too late.

Comment: The .dsp file contains setting for each project in workspace. I am looking for the VC6 IDE setting. Anyway, thank you @HansPassant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're stored in the registry at:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\DevStudio\6.0\Build System\Components\Platforms\Win32 (x86)\Directories]
```

So you could use regedit to export a registry file if you want.

It's not what you asked, but in most cases, you're probably better off storing directory information as project settings (in the .dsp file).  It makes working on multiple projects (and multiple versions) easier.